# Mongoose subschema array virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am posting this question and the answer in hopes it will help someone else (or if there's a better answer).

How to I create virtuals for Mongoose nested schemas when in array form?

Here are the schemas:

```
var Variation = new Schema({
  label: {
    type: String
  }
});

var Product = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  }

  variations: {
    type: [Variation]
  }
});
```

How I would like a virtual on `variations`. It seems that if the sub doc is not an array then we can simply do this:

```
Product.virtual('variations.name')...
```

But that only works for non arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to define the virtual as part of the subschema rather than parent and it must be done **before** the subschema is assigned to parent. Access to the parent object can be done via `this.parent()`:

```
var Variation = new Schema({
  label: {
    type: String
  }
});

// Virtual must be defined before the subschema is assigned to parent schema
Variation.virtual("name").get(function() {

  // Parent is accessible
  var parent = this.parent();
  return parent.title + ' ' + this.label;
});


var Product = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  }

  variations: {
    type: [Variation]
  }
});
```